# Read/Write from Sheets is suddenly incredibly slow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a large script project that I've been working on for a couple of years that our company is using to track production in a manufacturing environment. Typically, the doGet function that loads the web interface for the tracking tool will execute in 5-15 seconds and is very snappy and responsive. However, since yesterday morning that function is taking 60-90 seconds per execution, and occasionally the web app doesn't open at all (even though I don't get a failure in the log for the doGet function). I've been out of vacation since last week and I'm the only developer with access to the code, so nothing in the code base has changed, and the underlying data in a Google sheet doesn't seem to have had any major shifts either.

I've narrowed things down to see that the reads/writes from/to Google Sheets is the main source of the slow down. I'm reading the data in a batch with getValues(), but a single call to that function on the ~850 rows x 9 columns is now taking almost 20 seconds, where the doGet function (which includes 3-4 getValues calls) ran in less than that as of a few days ago.

I'm completely at a loss for how to debug this issue. Here are a few lines of code from the beginning of my doGet function if it helps. There is more to the function than this, but I can look at the time stamps on the Logger statements to tell that this getValues is running way too slow.

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEETIDHERE");
  var pst = ss.getSheetByName("Panel Status Tracker");
  Logger.log("Start Panel Data Get")
  var panelData = pst.getRange(9, 1, pst.getLastRow()-8, 8).getValues();
  Logger.log("End Panel Data Get")
```

TIA!

Comment: A few lines of code is not a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Cooper, but I'm not exactly sure what else to provide. The getValues call in doGet was running fine, now it's not. For security reasons I can't give others access to my sheet to be able to run my scripts, so I'm left trying to find out why the read operation is suddenly running so slow. There's nothing else in my code that is called before this, and while there is code called after it, the time stamps have determined that there is a problem in the snippet I posted.

Comment: Well then I'd recommend to learn how to use the debugger better or Logger.log() or console.log. It looks like you're going to have to solve your own problem

Comment: That's incredbily unhelpful Cooper, so thanks for the warm welcome to the community. I'm not sure what other info Loggers are going to provide when it's just a situation that a call to the Google servers has suddenly slowed down massively, but if you can point me to a resource, I'm always glad to learn.

Comment: The code you shared is simple code right out of the google apps script documentation I presume you already know where that is.  There's not much to say about you problem if you can supply a [mcve] .

Comment: (Mental note: Precognition is indispensable - if only you had taken detailed "baseline" measures of problem and execution characteristics.)

Answer (score 0):

These symptoms would usually suggest that the number of rows in the sheet has increased. Remove any unneeded blank rows at the bottom of the sheet and see if that helps.

If blank rows keep reappearing, chances are that you have a erroneous array formula somewhere in the sheet that causes runaway expansion.

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but there are no blank rows at the bottom of the sheet, and I keep a careful eye on that to make sure it doesn't cause an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding console.time('sec1') and console.timeEnd('sec1') at various sections of your code to figure out which section takes the most time. If you figure out the section of code, try figuring out the exact line by adding subsections within that section.

[**console.time()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time)